# How to verify incremental checkpoints working in Apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am implementing incremental checkpoints using RocksDB as statebackend in my flink code, but i want to know is incremental checkpoints are happening what i meant is there way to check logs or flink dashboard whether it is performing incremental checkpoints or full checkpoints

1. I am using flink version 1.10.0 as per flink documentation i saw logging mechanism is disabled in Flink version 1.10.0 i followed this [Ververica](https://ververica.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015933320-How-to-get-RocksDB-s-LOG-file-back-for-advanced-troubleshooting) link to enable RocksDB logging below is code for enabling logging i used

```java
    import static org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigOptions.key;
    
    import java.util.Collection;
    import org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigOption;
    import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
    import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory;
    import org.rocksdb.DBOptions;
    import org.rocksdb.InfoLogLevel;
    
    public class DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactoryWithLog extends DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        private String dbLogDir = "";
    
        @Override
        public DBOptions createDBOptions(DBOptions currentOptions,
                                         Collection<AutoCloseable> handlesToClose) {
            currentOptions = super.createDBOptions(currentOptions, handlesToClose);
    
            currentOptions.setInfoLogLevel(InfoLogLevel.INFO_LEVEL);
            currentOptions.setStatsDumpPeriodSec(60);
            currentOptions.setDbLogDir(dbLogDir);
    
            return currentOptions;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().toString() + "{" + super.toString() + '}';
        }
    
        /**
         * Set directory where RocksDB writes its info LOG file (empty = data dir, otherwise the
         * data directory's absolute path will be used as the log file prefix).
         */
        public void setDbLogDir(String dbLogDir) {
            this.dbLogDir = dbLogDir;
        }
    
        public static final ConfigOption<String> LOG_DIR =
                key("state.backend.rocksdb.log.dir")
                        .stringType()
                        .noDefaultValue()
                        .withDescription("Location of RocksDB's info LOG file (empty = data dir, otherwise the " +
                                "data directory's absolute path will be used as the log file prefix)");
    
        @Override
        public DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory configure(Configuration configuration) {
            DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactory optionsFactory =
                    super.configure(configuration);
    
            this.dbLogDir = configuration.getOptional(LOG_DIR).orElse(this.dbLogDir);
    
            return optionsFactory;
        }
```

I did below settings in my code to enable logging

```java
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    
    env.enableCheckpointing(interval);
    env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    
    RocksDBStateBackend stateBackend = new RocksDBStateBackend(incrementalCheckpointPath,true);
    
    DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactoryWithLog options = new DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactoryWithLog();
    options.setDbLogDir("file:///mnt/flink/storage/rocksdb/logging/");
    
    env.setStateBackend(stateBackend);
    
    stateBackend.setRocksDBOptions(options);
```

I added below 2 setting in my flink configuration file to enable RocksDB logging

```java
    state.backend.rocksdb.log.dir: "file:///mnt/flink/storage/rocksdb/logging/"
    state.backend.rocksdb.options-factory: com.myflinkcode.common.config.DefaultConfigurableOptionsFactoryWithLog
```

I went through complete flink dashboard but i didn't get any clue how to check is incremental checkpoint is happening or full checkpointing is happening. Please help me how can i set logging for RocksDB to know that incremental checkpoints is happening or not. I saw in the documentation RocksDB logging will cause huge cost in performance as well as the storage this is for testing purpose after that i will disable that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this information is logged or displayed anywhere, but in your code you could use

```java
stateBackend.isIncrementalCheckpointsEnabled()
```

to determine if your RocksDB state backend has checkpoints enabled, and then log this information yourself.

Note that to enable incremental checkpoints (which are off by default), you'll need to configure

```yaml
state.backend.incremental: true
```